# How to restart the c# application without exiting from the application

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

How to restart a c# application program or call

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ConnectPage());

    }
```

, without exiting the program?

I have tried the `process.Start()` method but this method starts another process which cannot be debugged anymore.

Comment: Try calling `Main()`?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE that won't work. David, what do you mean "restart"? Typically restart means restart, I'm not sure how you restart a program without exiting it. Application.Restart will restart it, but it will exit first. I'm assuming you are using an Express Visual Studio, otherwise you would be able to re-attach the debugger.

Comment: Restart without exiting??

Comment: “I need **X**. Hmm, I bet restarting the application without exiting will get me **X**! _code... code... code...._ Ohh, why is it not working?? I'll ask on Stack Overflow...”. You need to tell us what **X** is.

Comment: Sorry, it means that next time it will go to debug mode also not just run the application exe

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(
  {

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    do{
      var page = new ConnectPage();
      Application.Run(page);
    } while (page.SomePropertyOrMethodToKeepAnOptionToRestart);
}
```

Keep in mind this is not a true restart, especially if you're storing things in static properties or fields.

Alternatively you can do something along these lines:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Application.Exit();
```

and then in your `Main` add

```
#if DEBUG
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

Comment: Hi, Sten Petrov. I have tried the first one, "page.SomePropertyOrMethodToKeepAnOptionToRestart" not found .

Comment: The second one works but will ask user to select the debugger engine, is it possible to remove the messagebox to ask user about this? Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to define that property yourself and set its value to false when you really want to exit the app